# How Can Compare Database Table Name With Textbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008-r2

I making create table button in visual studio with C#. But I have problem create table function. If I use same table name when I create table, I get error. How can I compare my textbox with database table names?

```
if(txtbox_loladı.Text=)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string Sql = "CREATE TABLE " + txtbox_loladı.Text + " (No nvarchar(50), [Name Surname] nvarchar(50), PRIMARY KEY (No))";
            Cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
            SqlDataReader SQLDR = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Table Has Been Created!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Need Change Table Name");
        }
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <tablename>; CREATE TABLE <...>;` ?

Comment: There is a system view called INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables that contains the names of all tables already present in your database. You can query this view to check if the name typed in the textbox already exists.

Comment: What is your code and what is your error?

Comment: I wanna compare txtbox text and table name, but I don't know and I can't find how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do that. Use `create table` **`if not exists`** command instead

**Edit:**

[this does the trick](https://lonewolfonline.net/sql-server-create-table-if-not-exists/): example:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='tbl_name' and xtype='U')
    CREATE TABLE tbl_name (
        Name varchar(64) not null
    )
GO
```

**with your code:**

```
string Sql = "IF NOT EXISTS SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='" + txtbox_loladı.Text + "' and xtype='U') "
Sql += "CREATE TABLE " + txtbox_loladı.Text + " (No nvarchar(50), [Name Surname] nvarchar(50), PRIMARY KEY (No))";
// I don't know whether you need "Go" as well
```

And you should use `$" {...} ... {...}"` instead of `"..." + .. + "..."`

Comment: Thanks for helping :) This code work for me. How can I do this for messagebox. I need make warning for user.

Comment: Well, if we separate the `select` part from my code: `var Sql = $"SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='{txtbox_loladı.Text}' and xtype='U')";` and execute, it results in an empty `SqlDataReader` when there is no such table. You would look for `if (SQLDR.HasRows)` and print `MessageBox.Show("table exists")`. But it's better to use `Cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead! This (oppose to a reader which returns all rows) only returns a single value. You would do `var tableCnt = (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar()` with a small change (replace `*` to `count(*)`) in `string Sql`. Then: `if(tableCnt > 0) //table exists`